# Gust cantrip... can we make it better?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, cantrips

The *gust* cantrip does have some pretty neat uses, however compared to the other elemental cantrips it is underwhelming for two reasons:

1. It doesn't have any lingering effects useful for utility
2. It has extra Verbal component.

How would we add something cool to make it a bit more of a fair shake but keep it within the cantrip power level?

My first thoughts:

> *Transmutation cantrip* 
> **Casting Time:** 1 action 
> **Range:** 30 feet 
> **Components:** V, S   (change to S) 
> **Duration:** Instantaneous (optionally up to 1 hour )
>
> You seize the air and compel it to create one of the following effects
> at a point you can see within range:
>
> - One Medium or smaller creature that you choose must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pushed up to 5 feet away from you.
> - You create a small blast of air capable of moving one object that is neither held nor carried and that weighs no more than 5 pounds. The
>   object is pushed up to 10 feet away from you. It isn’t pushed with
>   enough force to cause damage.
> - You create a harmless sensory affect using air, such as causing leaves to rustle, wind to slam shutters shut, or your clothing to
>   ripple in a breeze.

Ideas for cantrip improvement:

- > You create a small zone (5' cube) of flowing air.  This air will continually blow for one hour and pick up any loose items and blow them out of the cube.

  Comment: This seems like it could be too powerful already... but a lot of DM's already allow this to be used to push sailboats (even though it shouldn't work RAW) and this would make an argument for it actually working.
- > You create a small zone (5' cube) of flowing air.  This air will continually blow for one hour, pick up any loose items, and blow them out of the cube. Any creature attempting to move through this area treats it as difficult terrain. This lasts for up to 1 hour*.

  Comment: Similar to mold earth ability.
- > You create an area of swirling and buffeting wind in a 5' cube Loose objects are picked up and swirled around.  Any loose projectile weapon passing through the square suffers disadvantage on the attack.*

  Comment: Likely too strong. 1d4 off of the attack roll? (one square of missile weapon bane?)
- > If you cast this spell multiple times, you can have no more than two of its non-instantaneous effects active at a time, and you can dismiss such an effect as an action.

Which of these improvements keep this cantrip within the cantrip power level?

Comment: Yeah, I got mixed up with my accounts.. its been a while since posting on SE.

Comment: @A.A so you have it: you can merge accounts following the instructions at https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. To be clear: you're not *required* to--it is permissible to maintain multiple accounts on a Stack as long as you don't do anything with the two that wouldn't be possible with one. (I.e. upvoting yourself multiple times, posting from one account and answering from the other, &c.)

Comment: @A.A I future please flag comments that are no longer needed as opposed to asking the clouds. It's far more useful. I've cleared out the obsolete ones for now. As for responses to the content itself: answering the question should be done as answers and be complete, which means some questions that are difficult to answer have to wait a bit. Trying to pester others into answering the question (which is how that comment read to me, though I'm certain you didn't intent to), isn't useful to anyone.